# Proof on cartesian product of compacts

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact sets, consider $\mathcal{A}$ an open cover of $X\times Y$.

Consider a point $x\in X$, where $\{x \}\times Y$ is homeomorphic to $ Y$ and, therefore, $\{x \}\times Y$ is compact. Thus, there exists a finite subcover $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^m$ of $\mathcal{A}$ that covers $\{x \} \times Y$. By the Tube Lemma, we can find an open set $W\times Y$ such that $W\times Y \subseteq \{x \}\times Y$. Note that this is also contained in $\bigcup_{i=1}^m A_i$.

So, for every set of the form $\{x \}\times Y$, there exists $W_x\times Y$ that is covered by a finite number of sets from $\mathcal{A}$. Furthermore, $\{W_x\in X\}$ covers $X$ with open sets, and as this is compact, it admits a finite subcover $\xi=\{W_1, W_2,\dots , W_k\}$ with which
$$ \bigcup_{j=1}^{k} W_{k}\times Y$$
forms a finite subcover of $X\times Y$, then $X\times Y$ is compact.

This may work, plus I have a couple of questions I hope you can answer

1.Is there any place where I can find the proof that $\{x \}\times Y$ is homeomorphic to $Y$
2.Regarding the tube lemma, what is the correct statement of the lemma that works for this proof?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You consider a point $x \in X$ where $\{x\} \times Y$ is homeomorphic to $X \times Y$, hence showing $\{x\} \times Y$ is compact. First, such a point may not exist in general, e.g. if $Y$ is non-empty and finite and $X$ contains more than one point. Second, it appears you are assuming the conclusion that $X \times Y$ is compact here. I would assume that you meant to write $\{x\} \times Y$ is homeomorphic to $Y$ (which is compact) and proceed from there, but you've explicitly asked about this, which makes me think this might be typo in whatever proof you're reading.

Comment: That's right, I should have written $\{x \} \times Y \simeq Y$

Comment: Excellent. Does that answer your first question? If so, I would delete it from your question.

Comment: Well, it doesn't really solve the question at all as I was wondering if the proof (having fixed the typo) is somewhere I can look it up

Comment: I see. The homeomorphism between $\{x\} \times Y$ and $Y$ is just $(x, y) \mapsto y$. I suspect that proving it is a homeomorphism is not usually explicitly proven, since it's a relatively straightforward exercise in topology. I would recommend trying to prove it for yourself.

Comment: "$W\times Y\subseteq \{x\}\times Y$." requires that either $W = \{x\}$ or $W = \emptyset$. You can look up the [Tube Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tube_lemma#Statement) yourself to figure out the correct statement. But I don't see where it is helpful here. To show that $X\times Y$ is compact, you need to find a subcover from $\scr A$, not from $\{W_x \times Y : x\in X\}$. For each $x$, there is a finite subcover of $\{x\}\times Y$. The union of those subcovers is not necessarily finite, but their projections onto $X$ form an open cover of it....